# Is there a way to put a pie chart into a dashboard?

Tags: matplotlib

Here's how my code looks like

```
#create figure to be used as dashboard
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16, 10), constrained_layout = True)

# Use GridSpec to determine the dimensions of the dashboard
gs = GridSpec(nrows = 2, ncols = 2, figure = fig)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1])
```

And my code for creating the pie chart is here

```
country = df.groupby('customer_country')['orderid'].count()
country = country.sort_values(ascending = False)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.title('Proportion of Orders From Countries', fontsize = 15)
plt.pie(country, 
    explode=(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
    labels = country.index, 
    autopct='%1.1f%%',
    pctdistance = 0.7)
```

I know that when plotting graphs into a dashboard used ax1.bar() or ax2.plot() or something but I'm unsure of pie charts.

I appreciate any and all suggestions :))

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pie.html

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I figured it out. I had to remove plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
Thank you to anyone who took a look at my question.